# Upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 20.04.02 on a Dell 7530 now most attached devices are not working: sound, usb camera, headset, wi-fi adapter not found

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, sound, usb

I recently performed a planned upgrade of 20.04 LTS to 20.04.02 and subsequently lost most of the device drivers (I assume) - no sound (just says 'dummy output'), no usb camera, USB keyboard doesn't work, no usb headset and no wi-fi adapter found. (they were working previously of course).

If I goto software updater it says I'm fully up to date!

If I run `lusb` I can see:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:81b6 Dell Computer Corp. DW5811e Snapdragon™ X7 LTE
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 12d1:4321 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. UVC Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 047f:c058 Plantronics, Inc. Plantronics Blackwire 3225 Series
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0737 Microsoft Corp. Compact Optical Mouse 500
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 8087:0025 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a5c:5832 Broadcom Corp. 5880
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:021e Apple, Inc. Aluminum Mini Keyboard (ISO)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:1005 Apple, Inc. Keyboard Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So it can see them.. just doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to force Ubuntu to install all the missing software? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Check results from terminal for `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Nothing with the $(uname -r) flag, but without that:

linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-22-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-40-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-41-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-43-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-44-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-45-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-48-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-49-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-50-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-53-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-55-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-59-generic

Should I have several different ones in there?

Comment: Since the results were empty, you will have to boot into another kernel and install the linux-modules-extra for the newest kernel

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy31 , I was just about to try your suggestion; with uname -r my kernel reports as: 5.11.0-22-lowlatency 

However neither the: linux-headers-5.11.0-22-lowlatency or the linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-22-lowlatency appear to exist?

E: Package 'linux-headers-5.11.0-22-lowlatency' has no installation candidate

E: Package 'linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-22-lowlatency' has no installation candidate